# Python format for list (on a single line)

Tags: python, list, format

I've doing research how to output python list in a formatted manner on a single line: Let me explain what I mean. Let's suppose I have the list "x".

```
x=[1.11111, 2.22222, 3.33333]
print(3*"%f4.2" % (x))

TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

Expected output:

```
[1.11, 2.22, 3.33]
```

Optionally, I can do something like:

```
[print("%4.2f" % xx) for xx in x]
```

but the output is on a separate line:

In fortran (for arrays) for example you can do:

```
write(6,'3(f4.2)')x
```

and everything will be displayed on a single line.

Anything similar for python lists?

Comment: You can use ```print([round(i, 2) for i in x])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing in the list comprehension.
You should print the list created with the list comprehension.

```py
>>> print(["%4.2f" % xx for xx in x])
['1.11', '2.22', '3.33']
```

But that would be still strings, because you are using string formatting. To get numbers (floats) you can use the round() function:

```py
>>> print([round(xx, 2) for xx in x])
[1.11, 2.22, 3.33]
```